# Enabling Enhanced Lookups

Tags: administration, lookup, bestpractice

Does anyone know of any *disadvantages* (or compelling reasons NOT to enable) **Enhanced Lookups**?

I don't see any references to such information in Google and Stack Exchange searches.  My knee-jerk reaction is to enable them, but my responsible side wants to know of any caveats that have been (hopefully) documented.

Thanks!

**Related SF Help page:**  https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=search_enhanced_lookup_enable.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not found a reason **not** to enable them. They are very useful for end users. They might make search time longer in very large databases but generally it seems the trade off of improved ability is a good one.